# How to remove ticks in ImageGrid?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I remove the ticks and numbers while keeping the row-title in ImageGrid?

```
grid[j].axis("off")
```

Removes the label Input, Ground Truth, Prediction whereas

```
grid[j].set_xticklabels([])
grid[j].set_yticklabels([])
```

only removes the numbers but not the dashes on the axis. I looked through https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_grid.ImageGrid.html but it doesn't seem to have an option to have no ticks.

```
for idx in range(0,1):
    fig  = plt.figure(idx, (15, 10))
    grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 10), axes_pad=0.1)  
    grid[0].set_ylabel("Input",rotation=0)
    grid[10].set_ylabel("Ground Truth",rotation=0)
    grid[20].set_ylabel("Variational ConvLSTM",rotation=0)
    for j in range(10):
        #grid[j].set_xticklabels([])
        #grid[j].set_yticklabels([])
        #grid[j].axis("off") This removes the title
        grid[j].imshow(x_true[idx,j], cmap="gray")
        grid[j+10].imshow(x_true[idx,j+10], cmap="gray")
        grid[j+20].imshow(x_temp[idx,j], cmap="gray")
```

Here is the output I currently have. It should ideally have no ticks (the dashes) and no numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to do it is to set `share_all = True` then

```
grid[0].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
grid[0].get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
```

so all the ticks get disabled

```
for idx in range(0,1):
    fig  = plt.figure(idx, (15, 10))
    grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols=(3, 10), axes_pad=0.1, share_all=True)  

    grid[0].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
    grid[0].get_xaxis().set_ticks([])

    # labels
    grid[0].set_ylabel("Input",rotation=0)
    grid[10].set_ylabel("Ground Truth",rotation=0)
    grid[20].set_ylabel("Prediction",rotation=0)
    for j in range(10):
        #grid[j].set_xticklabels([])
        #grid[j].set_yticklabels([])
        #grid[j].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])
        #grid[j].get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
        #grid[j].axis("off")
        grid[j].imshow(x_true[idx,j], cmap="gray")
        grid[j+10].imshow(x_true[idx,j+10], cmap="gray")
        grid[j+20].imshow(x_temp[idx,j], cmap="gray")
```

[image]